# Is there another way to handle exception in Range Operator in swift?

Tags: swift

I am pretty much new to swift so, please bear with me :)

what if, in the following code

```
for i in (1...(self.count - 1)) { //(self.count is number of elements in Array Extension)
    print(i)
}
```

self.count becomes 1.

well.. i can always work like the following

```
if self.count > 1
{
    for i in (1...(self.count - 1)) {
        print(i)
    }
}
else
{
    for i in ((self.count - 1)...1) {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

but is there another (probably better) way to deal with this ?

in which i won't have to use if-else control statements

PS :- as suggested in the comments,  I have also used

```
for i in [(1...(self.count - 1))]
{
    print(i)        
}
```

but it still crashes when self.count = 1

Comment: `for i in indices { ... }`

Comment: downgraded my answer to a comment you could use this: for i in **(1...(count > 1 ? (count - 1) : 1))** { print("\(i)") }

Comment: @LeoDabus : it still crashes when self.count = 1. I have changed to "for i in [(1...(self.count - 1))]"

Comment: Btw what is self.count ? is it the number of elements of an array extension? Is it just an integer property? Your question is unclear

Comment: @LeoDabus : self.count is number of elements in Array Extension

Comment: @LeoDabus : "**for i in [(1...(j - 1))] where j > 1**" gives me a run time error when j = 1.  and "**for i in [(1...(j - 1))] where i > 0**" gives me compile time error. i have replaced self.count with "j". I am really sorry if i am being really annoying. thanks for having patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over *all* array indices, use the `..<` range operator which
*omits* the upper bound:

```
for i in 0 ..< array.count { }
```

or better:

```
for i in array.indices { }
```

The latter has the advantage that it works also for collections with
indices which are not zero-based (such as `ArraySlice`).

To iterate over all indices but the first,

```
for i in array.indices.dropFirst() { }
```

works in all cases, even if the array is empty. You should also check
if you really need the indices, or if you actually want to iterate
over the array *elements*, such as

```
for elem in array.dropFirst() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with range exceptions is to just not cause them
in the first place ;)

Why not just use a zero based index and then adjust it later in the loop if needed?

```
extension Array {
    func oneBasedIndices() -> [Int] {
        return (0..<count).map { return $0 + 1 }
    }
}
```

The smallest number `Array`'s `count` member can ever be is `0` and `0..<0` will never fail, so maybe something like this extension would do the trick if what you want is 1 based indices.